Is there a keyboard shortcut for simply 'save and return to entries list'? Craft 4/5
I know about the 'save and continue editing' and 'save as new entry' shortcuts, but there doesn't appear to be a keyboard shortcut for saving and returning to the entries list. I have checked documentation, nothing there.

I guess the answer is NO :(

Not exactly, however just like any normal form in html, you can trigger the standard submission by pressing Enter while focus is inside a plain text field such as the entry title. That'll get you back to the index list.
